# Trying to get lxml to print a specific number in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to get lxml to print the selected in python:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlnBn.jpg

The code I have isn't much but here it is

```
from lxml import html
import requests


page = requests.get('https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1703834')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

winner = tree.xpath(//*[@id="eventView0"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7])

print,winner
```

Comment: What specifically is the issue/error you are encountering? In other words, what is your expected result, and what is the result are you getting instead?

Comment: The specific one I'm getting is :

winner = tree.xpath(//*[@id="eventView0"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7])
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


However I'm not even sure that I'm going about the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error you see is because you have not enclosed the XPath string into quotes, fix it:

```
winner = tree.xpath('//*[@id="eventView0"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]')
```

The *actual* problem is that the *table content is dynamically formed* via JavaScript that is executed in the browser. What you can do is to parse the `script` tag that has the desired data inside the JSON object, extract the JSON string and load it into the Python data structure via `json.loads()`:

```
import json
import re

from lxml import html
import requests


page = requests.get('https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1703834')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

script = tree.xpath('//script[contains(., "var json")]/text()')[0]
obj_string = re.search(r"var json = (\{.*?\}),$", script, re.MULTILINE).group(1)
obj = json.loads(obj_string)

# print entries
entries = obj['ladder']['entries']
for entry in entries:
    print(entry['account']['name'])
```

Prints account names (just as a proof it is working):

```
Havoc6
Steelmage
Olecgolec
...
Anafobia
nokieka2
HoGji
```

Comment: This worked! Unfortunately since I "have under 15 rep" you can't see my upvotes!

Comment: I upvoted for you AveryLipsit this should be the accepted answer to the question. @alecxe, can you please edit your answer to include my answer on regarding the syntax error so that those who come looking for an answer to a similar problem will find a complete answer?

Answer (score 1):

A syntax error means you are writing invalid python, and that does not necessarily mean there is something wrong with your logic/approach.

Make sure to surround the argument inside your invocation of tree.xpath with single quotes.

```
winner = tree.xpath('//*[@id="eventView0"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]')
```

Comment: Thanks, now the error is gone but it's still not printing anything. It just says "Process finished with exit code 0"